# Injecting dependencies inside @Provides methods with Dagger 2

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have these three dependencies correctly created (I verified it by debugging that they indeed exist) using Dagger 2, let's call them `a, b, c`, like so:

```
class Example {
    ...
    @Inject A a;
    @Inject B b;
    @Inject C c;
    ...
},
```

provided by `SomeModule` as follows:

```
@Module
class SomeModule {
    ...
    @Singleton @Provides A provideA(){return new A()};
    @Singleton @Provides B provideB(){return new B()};
    @Singleton @Provides C provideC(){return new C()};
    ...
},
```

and the component is a fairly simple one:

```
@Component(modules = {SomeModule.class, ...})
class SomeComponent {
    ...
    void inject(Example example);
    ...
},
```

and I need them to create another objects, let's call them `d, e`, something like this:

```
public Example(){
    DaggerSomeComponent.builder().build().inject(this);
    ...
    this.d = new D(c);
    this.e = new E(d, a, b);
    ...
}
```

My question is: is it possible to get to something like this?

```
class Example {
    ...
    @Inject A a;
    @Inject B b;
    @Inject C c;
    @Inject D d;
    @Inject E e;
    ...
    public Example(){
        DaggerSomeComponent.builder().build().inject(this);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [`@Provides` methods can take parameters](https://google.github.io/dagger//users-guide.html#satisfying-dependencies). Dagger will create instances before invoking the method.

```
@Provides D provideD(C c){return new D(c)};
@Provides E provideE(A a, B b, D d){return new E(d, a, b)};
```